# Do other wolves wake up during the werewolf phase in ONUW?

Tags: werewolf, one-night-werewolf

Do all werewolves awake during the werewolf phase or only characters explicitly titled "werewolf"? Does Mystic Wolf wake up? What about Dream Wolf? I would think yes because otherwise how would you know who is on team werewolf, but I'm also lead to believe no because Dream Wolf doesn't wake up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the Dream Wolf, all wolves wake up at the start of the Night phase. That's what makes the Dream Wolf special. The [Daybreak rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/109880/daybreak-rules), in describing the roles, make this clear:

Alpha Wolf:

> At night, the Alpha Wolf wakes with the other Werewolves. Afterwards, the Alpha Wolf wakes up separately.

Mystic Wolf:

> The Mystic Wolf wakes with the other Werewolves. Afterwards, the Mystic Wolf wakes up separately.

Dream Wolf:

> The Dream Wolf does *not* wake up with the other Werewolves.